# Linq filtering by class array properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5

My schema is as [image]

I am currently getting the products with valiants like so

```
    products = context.Products
       .Include(x => x.Skus)
       .Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
           .ThenInclude(pv => pv.Option)
       .Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
           .ThenInclude(pv => pv.Value);
```

Now i am trying to add a filter functionality by `OptionId` and `ValueId`

The following list holds both the `OptionId` and the `ValueId` for every option selected at the UI

```
   List<Filter> filters;
```

where Filter is

```
public class Filter
{
    public int Oid { get; set; } //OptionId
    public int Vid { get; set; } //ValueId
}
```

How could i add filter functionality on this one?

After using

```
var v = context.Products.Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
    .Where(prod => prod.ProductVariants
    .Any(v => filters.Any(f => f.Oid == v.OptionId && f.Vid == v.ValueId)));
```

i got the error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ProductVariant>()
    .Where(p0 => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: Product
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
        IsNullable: False
    , "Id") != null && object.Equals(
        objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(EntityShaperExpression: 
            EntityType: Product
            ValueBufferExpression: 
                ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False
        , "Id"), 
        objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(p0, "ProductId")))
    .Any(p0 => __filters_0
        .Any(f => f.o == p0.OptionId && f.v == p0.ValueId))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

**Update**
While using

```
    var vv = context.ProductVariants
        .Where(v => filters.Any(f => f.Oid == v.OptionId && f.Vid == v.ValueId)).AsEnumerable();
```

The error is now

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ProductVariant>()
    .Where(p => __filters_0
        .Any(f => f.Oid == p.OptionId && f.Vid == p.ValueId))' could not be translated.
```

**Update**
The error persists even with only filter by option

```
    var vv = context.ProductVariants
        .Where(v => filters.Any(f => f.Oid == v.OptionId)).AsEnumerable();
```

**Update** The classes used are

```
    public class Product
        {
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            public IEnumerable<ProductVariant> ProductVariants { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Sku> Skus { get; set; }
        }

public enum FilterType
    {
        CheckBox,
        Radio,
        Button,
        List
    }

    public class Option
    {
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public string OptionName { get; set; }

        public FilterType FilterType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public int ValueId { get; set; }
        public string OptionValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sku
    {
        public int SkuId { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductVariant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public int OptionId { get; set; }

        public int ValueId { get; set; }

        public int SkuId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OptionId")]
        public Option Option { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ValueId")]
        public Value Value { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SkuId")]
        public Sku Sku { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update**
I have narrowed the error to be related with the `Filter` class

By using

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
ints.Add(1);
```

and

```
    var vv = context.ProductVariants
        .Where(v => ints.Any(f => f == v.OptionId));
```

it just works. Should i use an expression or something else?

```
static Expression<Func<...
```

Comment: What have you attempted? Your includes really are irrelevant. Also, it's poor practice to abbreviate names like that, especially given the explanatory comments they necessitate. Code should be self documenting where possible

Comment: Why include Sku when you don't use it?

Comment: Why does your Filter class have `Oid` and `Vid` but your query you claim is crashing has `f.o` and `f.v`?

Comment: @I have renamed Oid to o and Vid to v in FilterClass locally. Sorry for any confusion generated. I just updated the original entities

Comment: @CaiusJard The sku should be part of the model returned to the MVC view

Comment: Does it fail if you use a `KeyValuePair<int,int>` instead of a Filter?

Comment: @CaiusJard Unfortunately it fails also

Comment: But an `List<int[]>` works OK?

Comment: @CaiusJard That is true (Using EF Core 5.01 and MVC)

Comment: It is necessary to specify what ORM framework you are using. EF Core 5.0? EF Core 3.x? EF 6.3+?   The behavior of the LINQ parsers could differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, ended up with [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

```
  if (filters.Any())
  {
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

    foreach (var filter in filters)
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.ProductVariants.Any(x => x.OptionId == filter.o & x.ValueId == filter.v));

    products = products.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
  }

  products = products.AsQueryable()
    .Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
      .ThenInclude(pv => pv.Option)
    .Include(x => x.ProductVariants)
      .ThenInclude(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll likely end up looking like:

```
.Where(prod => prod.Variants.Any(v => filters.Any(f => f.Oid == v.OptionId && f.Vid == v.VariantId)))
```

If your ProductVariants entity has no Id (not sure how you set up your entities), you might need `f.Oid == v.Option.Id && f.Vid == v.Variant.Id`

Unless you actually need to select fields out of Sku, Option and Value they could be dropped from the query; realistically only product and product variant are needed for the filtering

Edit:

Looks like the ORM is struggling to turn the linq into SQL. Starting from product variant might help:

```
context.ProductVariants
  .Where(v => filters.Any(f => f.Oid == v.OptionId && f.Vid == v.VariantId))
```

If that works out, add your product in

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! Could you please check the update? I got an translation error and don't have a clue on how to fix it

Comment: Try starting with product variants, I’ll make an edit

Comment: It seems the error persists, at least it is narrowed down now. Just updated my question

Comment: You're going to need to post everything we need to reproduce it; I wasn't able to repro anything like it with a test code I have here using EFC5. The pattern of `var someList = ...; context.Collection.Where(c => someList.Any(i => ...))` is quite typical for generating queries there are multiple items to be returned

Comment: Just added the models used to generate the database

Comment: It seems the error is related to the Filter class. Can you check the update?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, even using all your classes and a brand new DB. I did have to remove the linkage between Product and Sku, because the migrations wouldn't apply because of cycles in the graph but other than that I just used the code you gave

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to replicate the problem with this code in a .net core winforms app and ef5:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WFNetCoreCSWithEF5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var f = new List<Filter>() { new Filter { Oid = 1, Vid = 2 } };
            var x = new ProductDbContext().ProductVariant.Where(pc => f.Any(f => f.Oid == pc.OptionId && f.Vid == pc.ValueId));
        }

    }


    public class Filter
    {
        public int Oid { get; set; } //OptionId
        public int Vid { get; set; } //ValueId
    }

    public class Product
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ProductVariant> ProductVariants { get; set; }
        //public IEnumerable<Sku> Skus { get; set; }
    }

    public enum FilterType
    {
        CheckBox,
        Radio,
        Button,
        List
    }

    public class Option
    {
        public int OptionId { get; set; }
        public string OptionName { get; set; }

        public FilterType FilterType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public int ValueId { get; set; }
        public string OptionValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sku
    {
        public int SkuId { get; set; }

        //public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        //public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductVariant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public int OptionId { get; set; }

        public int ValueId { get; set; }

        public int SkuId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OptionId")]
        public Option Option { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ValueId")]
        public Value Value { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SkuId")]
        public Sku Sku { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductVariant> ProductVariant { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sku> Skus { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Option> Options { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=c:\temp\new3.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    }
}
```

And these DOS commands:

```
dotnet ef migrations add X
dotnet ef database update
```

To create the db

Comment: I noticed that in your post you have removed ProductId from SKU and the Ienumerable<Sku> from product also. So to make this work i should change the schema?

Comment: I don't know - I removed it so that the migrations would build the DB for me without creating a circular dependency path in the foreign keys. If your DB already exists and somehow doesn't have a cycle in the path then that might be how come yours works. I do think it's a bit odd though, that you have product-sku-variant and also product-variant. It's like you can't decide what a sku relates to